# primfaces 5.3 uplaod csv file utf-8 encoding

Tags: java, jsf, utf-8, primefaces, upload

i am trying to import a csv file using primefaces upload file component , after importing some special characters like € does not display correctly.

the original encoding of the csv file is not utf-8

my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncoding</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.filter.util.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncoding</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

my form :

```
<h:form id="uploadForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8">
```

my input fileUpload :

```
< p:fileUpload id="uploadFileParamBtn" auto="true fileUploadListener="{myController.handleFileUpload}" label="upload" 
allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv)$/" sizeLimit="10000000"  />
```

My Filter class:

```
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {
@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    request.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}

@Override
public void init(final FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

  }

}
```

in jboss standlone.xml :

```
<system-properties>
     <property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
</system-properties>
```

primfaces 5.3

JSF 2.0

jboss-eap-6.2

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What is the problem? Uploading or displaying? And please revisit your question and edit it to format/display the code

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and sorry to be vague, for the formatting that I am in my first post on the site.
In fact, I am using the p: uploadFile to import a csv file, the import is done via apache apache common-csv, after the import, the data is stored in a database When displaying  these data  on the page in the browser
the symbol "€" is not displayed correctly, "?" is displayed in its place.

I hope I have been clearer.

Comment: A little more clear. But split your problem in 3... uploading, storing/retrieving in DB and downloading. When does the data get corrupted. That is the area you should focus on. Is it actually an uploading problem or a storing problem or...

Comment: The Storage in the database as well as the display is not a problem, indeed if i import a file encoded in utf-8 no problem arises, however if the csv is coded differently than utf-8 c is in this case that the problem occurs

Comment: would you have an idea that could help me please, I ask the question differently, why the csv file encoded with utf-8 is imported correctly, however when I import an encoded file other than utf-8 some characters pose the problem